# Cannot get form designer in Visual Studio to load a form

Tags: visual-studio

Designer error [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPAy4.png)

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainWindow));
        this.TC_mainControl = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
        this.TP_Payment = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.TP_Manage = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.TP_Batch = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.TP_Report = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.TP_COMM = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.TP_LOG = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.pay_sample1 = new POSLinkTest.Payment();
        this.man_sample1 = new POSLinkTest.Manage();
        this.batch_sample1 = new POSLinkTest.Batch();
        this.report_sample1 = new POSLinkTest.Report();
        this.comm_sample1 = new POSLinkTest.Commset();
        this.log_sample1 = new POSLinkTest.LogSetting();
        this.TC_mainControl.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // TC_mainControl
        // 
        this.TC_mainControl.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
                    | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.TC_mainControl.Controls.Add(this.TP_Payment);
        this.TC_mainControl.Controls.Add(this.TP_Manage);
        this.TC_mainControl.Controls.Add(this.TP_Batch);
        this.TC_mainControl.Controls.Add(this.TP_Report);
        this.TC_mainControl.Controls.Add(this.TP_COMM);
        this.TC_mainControl.Controls.Add(this.TP_LOG);
        this.TC_mainControl.ItemSize = new System.Drawing.Size(148, 20);
        this.TC_mainControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.TC_mainControl.Multiline = true;
        this.TC_mainControl.Name = "TC_mainControl";
        this.TC_mainControl.Padding = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 0);
        this.TC_mainControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.TC_mainControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 600);
        this.TC_mainControl.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.TabSizeMode.Fixed;
        this.TC_mainControl.TabIndex = 0;
        this.TC_mainControl.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TC_mainControl_SelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // TP_Payment
        // 
        this.TP_Payment.AutoScroll = true;
```

The solution builds without any errors?  Why will the form not load into the designer, yet it will compile?

Using Visual Studio 2015, Windows 10 64 bit

I can upload the project if necessary,  it is just Sample Project.

Answer (score 0):

The error message on the screenshot says that types from `POSLinkTest` namespace are not available. So probably add a reference to that namespace.

For future use there are some other potential problems with the designer code:

Removed parameterless constructor. Solution: add the parameterless constructor back as a privet constructor to prevent others from using it but having it available for the designer

Design time code (like `OnPaint` handler) that references resource not available at that time (like db connection). Solution: try not to handle that in UI related code.